# Rewrite image url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This htaccess example is marked as running. I have no experience with htaccess. What I want to do is rewrite the image urls with htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} h=([1-9]) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} w=([1-9]) 
RewriteRule (.*) resize.php?src=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

My htaccess and resize.php in same directory.
and my image:

```
<img src="<?= make_image($row->imgage,750,422); ?>">
```

**image helper**

```
function make_image($url, $w, $h){ 
  $str = parse_url($url);
  $exp = explode("/", $str["path"]);  
  $file = end($exp);
  $new_url = str_replace($url, 'https://www.example.com/public/tt/img/', $url);
  return $new_url . $file . '?h='.$h.'&w='.$w; 
}
```

**Directories:**

[image]

And the result:
[image]
I would appriciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: What is the idea behind the `(?i)`?

Comment: How are you determining that it "doesn't work"? What exactly are you expecting? The code you posted does "work" by itself. Although it does have a few oddities and could do with a few optimisations. Do you have any other directives?

Comment: @arkascha That's a regex-style case-insensitive match (mode modifier). (Alternative to the mod_rewrite `NC` flag.)

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you all your answers. btw sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> ```

This *condition* checks that the requested image URL maps to a physical file. However, according to your filesystem diagram, any request of the form `/public/tt/img/<filename>` does *not* exist as a physical file (there is no `/public/tt/img` directory), so the rule is never going to be processed.

It looks like you need to *negate* this condition and check that the request does **not** already map to a physical file, instead of checking that it does?

To do this, you need to prefix the *CondPattern* with a `!`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite for your answer. I replaced the rule with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ` But image return 400 bad request responses

Comment: This is old working htaccess `RewriteCond $1 !^(resize\.php)
RewriteRule ^(img)/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) resize.php?src=https://www.example.com/public/image/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [L]` bu i want use multiple image folder. for example /public/uploads/2020/ when i added second line this htaccess, naturally line 2 doesn't work.

Comment: The only significant difference would seem to be the query string you are passing to your `resize.php` script? I can't see where the 400 response is coming from? You've removed the `L` flag in your updated directive - you probably need that if you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I really bad at english. I can understand what you mean but I guess I can't express my problem correctly. Sorry about that.
this old htaccess work fine i commented above. but i can't use it anymore. because i have multiple direcories for calling images. I using htaccess in my question and your answer change someting. Sounds good cause i think we are on the right way.
when i `var_dump($_GET)` in my resize.php it returns `array(3) { ["src"]=> string(47) "/public/tt/img/filename_16x9_1527.jpg" ["h"]=> string(3) "422" ["w"]=> string(3) "750" }` but i can't understand 400 bad request.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I had to define two different patterns.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(resize\.php)
RewriteRule ^(img)/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) resize.php?src=https://www.example.com/public/image/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(uploads/(?:[0-9]{4}|members))/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) resize.php?src=https://www.example.com/public/$1/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [L]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive is not required here, given the stated `RewriteRule` _pattern_.